# Why is my non-inverting band-pass filter not working properly?

Tags: active-filter

I need to design a band-pass filter with the cutoff frequencies of f1=16384 Hz and f2=32768 Hz.

I calculated the values of the components and it seems right, but when I run the simulation f1=9kHz and f2=58kHz.

What can I do to obtain the cutoff frequencies of f1=16384 Hz and f2=32768 Hz?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The component values of C1, R1 and R2, C2 are correct. How are you obtaining the cutoff frequencies? Are you determining the -3 dB points properly?

Comment: I am using the Cutoff_Lowpass_3dB() and the Cutoff_Highpass_3dB() measurements in PSpice

Comment: Your plot spans an **enormous** frequency range, that will make extracting the cutoff frequencies a pain. I would run a frequency sweep from 1 kHz to 1 MHz (with at least 1000 points) and see if that is better. Then extract the numbers **by hand** from the graph. What do you get?

Comment: When i run the simulation from 1kHz to 1MHz and measure the values at -3dB i get f1=7.15kHz and f2=75.2k and this values change when i change the amplitude of the input signal

Comment: How many intermediate points is the AC simulation plotting? You need to plot many, many points to get an accurate result - did you not read that in the comments above?

Comment: I tried it even with 100000 points/decade and i get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to obtain the cutoff frequencies of f1=16384 Hz and f2=32768 Hz?

Since you don't provide the attenuations and you're trying to make a 2nd order filter, I'll assume this would fit your needs:

$$\begin{align}
f_1 &= 16384 \\
f_2 &= 32768 \\
BW &= f_2 - f_1 = 16384 \\
f_0 &= \sqrt{f_1f_2} \approx 23170.475 \\
Q &= \frac{f_0}{BW} = \sqrt2 \\
H(s) &= \frac{\frac{\omega_0}{Q}s}{s^2+\frac{\omega}{Q}s+\omega_0^2}\\
\end{align}$$

If you choose, for example, a [multiple-feedback bandpass](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php), and you specify the previously found center frequency, \$f_0\$, and the bandwidth, \$BW\$, you get this result which can be verified with a simulator of your choice (I used ideal components):

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

You can't design a bandpass filter that narrow with first order sections.

When you take the peak response at 20/25 kHz, and then find the frequencies at which the response is 3dB down on that, that will tell you what this filter is doing, but it won't get you to your target specification.

The problem with that is that with only first order filters, and a narrow passband, the peak will be suppressed by the combination of the passband loss due to the very gentle transition bands.

You can check this by modifying your circuit to have just one, or the other, filter element in circuit. You'll then find the -3dB frequencies come out as you calculated. Then check the amplitude response at the other frequency, and you'll find it's still around 1dB low. Those two lows up to suppress your peak from the expected +6dB.

A bandpass filter that narrow requires higher order sections, with steeper transition bands.

Comment: Thank you! What filter would you recommend to get the best result?

Comment: Generally narrow bandpass filters are best done as a resonant/mulitple feedback circuit, whereas wide bandpass are best done as a cascaded highpass and lowpass sections. One octave is narrow if your order is low with slowly rolling off stopbands, and wide if you have high order steep stopbands. Try Mr. Citizen's answer. The 'best' result? That's not a specification. Some people would want a flat passband, some steep stopbands, some flat group delay in the passband, some would want all of those. When you have a specification for both passband and stopband, then you can attempt to meet it.

Answer (score 0):

The two corner frequencies are so close together that they are interacting.  Your pass band is only one octave.  IIRC, in a standard single-pole response curve, the attenuation is -3 dB at the corner frequency and -1 dB one octave away from it.  This means that as a first-order approximation, the attenuation at each corner freq is an additional 1 dB from the other network.  IOW, there is no "flat" part in the middle of the passband between the two corners, and the overall circuit gain in the middle of the passband is not going to be +6 dB.  Relative to the input signal level, the output +3dB freqs will not be at the calculated values.

The opamp also might be contributing to things.  What is its gain-bandwidth product, and what is the gain margin at 131 kHz?

Neil beat me.  Must type faster ...

Comment: I appreciate your response, i tried it with different op amps but it seems like i need to design a narrow band-pass filter for my particular frequencies. Thank you!